# generate seo friendly url for multi language system

Tags: seo, htaccess, url-slug

I have this url's for multi language system using php :

```
http://mydomain/ <-- default language english (en)
http://mydomain/index.php?lang=de
http://mydomain/index.php?lang=fr
http://mydomain/index.php?lang=tr
```

Now, for another page i have this url:

```
http://mydomain/article.php?id=xx <-- show article details
http://mydomain/article.php?list=all  <-- show article archive
http://mydomain/gallery.php?id=xx
http://mydomain/faq.php?id=xx
http://mydomain/faq.php?list=all
http://mydomain/contact.php
```

Now, i need to create seo friendly url using php and htaccess Like This :

for index:

```
http://mydomain/  <-- for default
http://mydomain/de/
http://mydomain/fr/
```

for article ie:(domain/lang/id/title.html)

```
http://mydomain/de/articles/22/test.html
```

for page:

```
http://mydomain/de/contact.html
```

for archive:

```
http://mydomain/de/articles/listall.html
```

in htaccess i write this code for article :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html$ articles.php?id=$1
```

but this worked for one language not multiple language. how do can i create seo friendly url for multi language system?!

Comment: Can you clarify the last two sentences here?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like 
`RewriteRule ^([en|es|ru|de]{2})/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]`

Where you'll want to replace [en|es|ru|de] with the all valid 2-letter language codes your site uses. This will then take whatever is after the language-code in the URL, and use that as the "main" URL, and then effectively append ?lang=es to the "actual" URL, though the user will not see this, it will happen in the background.

Comment: this url not work for me: `http://mydomain/es/news/2/ss.html`

Comment: The rewrite I gave above will only handle 2 "parameters". The first for the language, the second for the filename. If you want to use an ID, you'll need to add a 3rd match (the parts in brackets). So if you want mydomain/de/news/2/ss.html to rewrite to mydomain/news.php?id=2&lang=de you'd need a rewrite like RewriteRule ^([en|es|ru|de]{2})/news/([0-9])/(.*) /news.php?id=$2&lang=$1 and then do that for each of your different URL structures (ie. articles, gallery, faq, etc.